# No Internet Access when using VPN

Tags: command-line, internet, vpn

I am having problems with my internet access. When using regular internet, it works just fine but when I connect using VPN, I couldn't access any website. I have tried to follow the basic troubleshooting steps from the other questions asked regarding the same issue but the terminal always asks for a password. This equipment I'm using is a company provided computer and I was not provided a password. What should I do next?

Comment: What VPN. Like NordVPN or ?
Did you manually add DNS and fixed the local IP.
Did you try on more devices or just one? Disabled IPv6? Try ping something with VPN on ?

Comment: If it is company provided computer and the VPN is to the same company, then you have to ask the company's IT department.

Comment: Only the company that supplied you the computer will know. We can not guess how they have it set up.

Answer (score 1):

> when I connect using VPN, I couldn't access any website

That is normal behavior when using a VPN. The only one that can fix this is the admin of the system that has the VPN installed.